# Install McAfee ePO in a secure environment

Tags: mcafee

I have a secure system running Server 2008 R2 and a GPO clamp based on the Microsoft secure baseline. I now want to install the McAfee ePO server onto the domain controller of the system and utilise the existing SQL Server (running on a different VM). Unfortunately I get an issue with one of the users involved not being able to log on as a batch process.

I understand that without giving a lot more detail of the system here, which I cannot do, it is not possible to tell me which user needs to be able to log into which machine as a batch process, but can anyone please point me at some documentation that describes what GPO permissions are required to install ePO?